# HANA SQL join alternatives to CROSS APPLY / LATERAL

Tags: sql, left-join, query-optimization, hana

I have a Microsoft SQL Server background and frequently use functionality such as `CROSS APPLY` and `CTE` (common table expressions) to write queries. I am currently trying to write a query in SAP HANA using `CROSS APPLY` but it does not appear to be supported.

I did find out that `LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL` is potentially the equivalent (or SQL standard) to Microsoft SQL Server `CROSS APPLY`, but it is not available in the SAP HANA version that I am working with (SAP HANA version 2.00.037.02.1562323855 [System -> Status]). It appears that this has been released in version [HANA 2.0 SPS04](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/04/11/whats-new-in-hana-2.0-sps04-sql/), but that is not what my company uses.

Here's a sample of the alternative to `CROSS APPLY` that I was using successfully in the past. But the performance appears to have become poor and I am getting out of memory errors. I suspect that the data set is growing and becoming quite large and the query is becoming inefficient.

```
FROM SAPECC.AUFK AS AUFK

LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY MANDT, OBJNR ORDER BY UDATE DESC) AS RowNumber
FROM SAPECC.JCDS
WHERE STAT = 'I0045' AND INACT = ''
) JCDS ON JCDS.OBJNR = AUFK.OBJNR AND JCDS.MANDT = AUFK.MANDT AND JCDS.RowNumber = 1
```

Any suggestions to an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try a correlated subquery instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select ...
from sapecc.aufk as a
left join sapecc.jcds as j
    on  j.objnr = a.objnr 
    and j.mandt = a.mandt
    and j.stat = 'I0045' 
    and j.inact = ''
    and j.udate = (
        select max(j1.udate)
        from sapecc.jcds as j1
        where 
            j1.objnr = a.objnr 
            and j1.mandt = a.mandt
            and j1.stat = 'I0045' 
            and j1.inact = ''
    )
```

This query should take advantage of an index on `(objnr, mandt, stat, inact, udate desc)`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the same CTE-approach that you're used from MSSQL with HANA:

```
WITH most_recent_JCDS as (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT *
              , ROW_NUMBER() 
                OVER (PARTITION BY MANDT, OBJNR 
                      ORDER BY UDATE DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM SAPECC.JCDS
        WHERE STAT = 'I0045' 
        AND INACT = '')
    WHERE   
        RowNumber = 1)

SELECT 
      AUFK. ...
    , JCDS. ...

FROM 
                         SAPECC.AUFK AUFK
    LEFT OUTER JOIN most_recent_JCDS JCDS
ON 
     (JCDS.OBJNR, JCDS.MANDT) 
   = (AUFK.OBJNR, AUFK.MANDT);
```

The concern about performance or query efficiency is something that can only be addressed by checking the actual execution.
PlanViz and EXPLAIN PLAN are the tools for this.

Assuming that some index "should" help provides a 50/50 chance of getting it correct (at best).

Comment: In the version of SAP HANA that I am using, I was not able to use CTE. I have received syntax errors in the past. Do you know if this is available in HANA version 2?

Comment: Yes, that worked even with HANA 1 and specifically with the HANA 2 SPS 3 you use.

Comment: When using your suggested CTE above, I get the following error; `ERROR [42000] [SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB DLL][HDBODBC] Syntax error or access violation;257 sql syntax error: incorrect syntax near "[": line 1 col 15 (at pos 15)`. It's odd since there is not a `[` character in the SQL and position 15 is not anywhere near a bracket / parenthesis.

Comment: Yeah, nah - that's not due to the CTE but something else. You may want to check the overall statement and/or break it down into smaller elements first. CTEs are definitively supported and working on your HANA version.

Comment: You're right, the application that I am using to extract data and run the report / SQL that I have is doing the following `SELECT * FROM [WITH JCDS AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY OBJNR, STAT ORDER BY UDATE ASC) AS RowNumber FROM SAPECC.JCDS WHERE STAT IN ('I0045','I0002') AND INACT = '' AND OBJNR LIKE 'OR%') SELECT TOP 100 * FROM JCDS WHERE RowNumber = 1]) T`. Probably because of concerns around SQL injection. I have to see if I can turn this off for my query.